# What are some ways to extract a partial list of form fields from a serialized JSON data string?

Tags: jquery

I already have a serialized JSON data string that I have extracted from the form fields

```
formData = $form.serializeArray();
```

`formData` contains `length`, `width` and `height` as "keys" of this string

How do I extract these from formData and set it up for `ajax`

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. Send what where exactly? And it looks like you have an array, not JSON and not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your form is [serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), you could use [inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to build an easy way to get data you need out of it.

This is an example of how you could do something like you requested. This code may work for your needs but it has not been tested.

```
var _findArray = ["length", "width", "height"];
var _newData = []; // Extracted data
$.each(formData, function(index, data) {
    if ($.inArray( data.name, _findArray ) !== -1) {
        _newData.push(data);
    }
});
```

Note: `_newData` will now have the extracted data

Comment: I'll take a wild guess that `$.inArray` never will return the boolean `false`, ever !

Comment: lol, yeah thanks for that. Like I said, not tested and I wrote that really fast!